# Using awk to process html-related Gift-format Moodle questions

Tags: awk, replace, moodle, gift

This is basically a awk question but it is about processing data for the [Moodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moodle)
[Gift](https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/GIFT_format) format, thus the tags.

I want to format html code in a question (Moodle "test" activity) but I need to replace < and > with the corresponding entities, as these will be interpreted as "real" html, and not printed.
However, I want to be able to type the question with regular code and post-process the file before importing it as gift into Moodle.

I thought awk would be the perfect tool to do this.

Say I have this (invalid as such) Moodle/gift question:

```
::q1::[html]This is a question about HTML:
<pre>
<p>some text</p>
</pre>
and some tag:<code><img></code>
{T}
```

What I want is a script that translates this into a valid gift question:

```
::q1::[html]This is a question about HTML:
<pre>
&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;
</pre>
and some tag:<code>&lt;img&gt;</code>
{T}
```

key point: replace < and > with `&lt;` and `&gt;` when:

1. inside a `<pre>`-`</pre>` bloc (assuming those tags are alone on a line)
2. between `<code>`and `</code>`, with arbitrary string in between.

For the first part, I'm fine. I have a shell script calling awk (gawk, actually).

```
awk -f process_src2gift.awk $1.src >$1.gift
```

with process_src2gift.awk:

```
BEGIN { print "// THIS IS A GENERATED FILE !" }
{
    if( $1=="<pre>" ) # opening a "code" block
    {
        code=1;
        print $0;
    }
    else
    {
        if( $1=="</pre>" ) # closing a "code" block
        {
            code=0;
            print $0;
        }
        else
        { # if "code block", replace < > by html entities
            if( code==1 )
            {
                gsub(">","\\&gt;");
                gsub("<","\\&lt;");
            }
            print $0;
        }
    }
}
END { print "// END" }
```

However, I'm stuck with the second requirement..

Questions:

1. Is it possible to add to my awk script code to process the hmtl code inside the `<code>` tags? Any idea ? I thought about using sed but I didn't see how to do that.
2. Maybe awk isn't the right tool for that ? I'm open for any suggestion on other (standard Linux) tool.

Comment: Any hint on why the downvote ? What [point](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) did I miss ?

Comment: didn't downvote. "They" probably did, because processing html inside awk is considered a non-starter ;-) . Usually what happens is you can solve this problem, and so you continue on until you get to a problem that is not reg-ex based and that can't be solved without standing on your head (in awk) AND then you need to learn html aware processes in a big rush. (Sorry I can't recommend a replacement tool). I don't see any reason that you can't extend the code you have to manage another flag var `code2`? to perform the same substitution. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the info. I understand processing html with awk is full of pitfalls but this is really a "side" case, Its not about processing a whole html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering own question.

I found a solution by doing a two step awk process:

- first step as described in question
- second step by defining `<code>` or `</code>` as field delimiter, using a regex, and process the string replacement on second argument ($2).

The shell file becomes:

```
echo "Step 1"
awk -f process_src2gift.awk $1.src >$1.tmp

echo "Step 2"
awk -f process_src2gift_2.awk $1.tmp >$1.gift

rm $1.tmp
```

And the second awk file (`process_src2gift_2.awk`) will be:

```
BEGIN { FS="[<][/]?[c][o][d][e][>]"; }
{
    gsub(">","\\&gt;",$2);
    gsub("<","\\&lt;",$2);
    if( NF >= 3 )
        print $1 "<code>" $2 "</code>" $3
    else
        print $0
}
```

Of course, there are limitations:

- no attributes in the `<code>` tag
- only one pair `<code></code>` in the line
- probably others...